# How can I combine two components in a Bigcommerce theme

Tags: php, html, bigcommerce

Ok so I am editing a Bigcommerce theme for a client. I don't have a lot of experience with Bigcommerce and only a little php. The current theme header is set up so that you can have the logo justified to the Left, center or right. Then depending on where the logo is, the search bar and Social Links take up the other 2 spaces.

I.E. is you have the logo to the left the search bar goes to the center and the social links go to the right.

The client would like to add another "logo" to the header and would like to combine the search bar and social links.

I'm looking at the markup for the header, it is set up like this

```
{{#if theme_settings.logo-position '==' 'left'}}
    <div class="header-logo header-logo--{{theme_settings.logo-position}} container">
        {{> components/common/store-logo}}
        {{> components/common/quick-search}}
        {{> components/common/social-links-header}}
    </div>
{{/if}}

{{#if theme_settings.logo-position '==' 'center'}}
    <div class="header-logo header-logo--{{theme_settings.logo-position}} container">
        {{> components/common/social-links-header}}
        {{> components/common/store-logo}}
        {{> components/common/quick-search}}
    </div>
{{/if}}

{{#if theme_settings.logo-position '==' 'right'}}
    <div class="header-logo header-logo--{{theme_settings.logo-position}} container">
        {{> components/common/social-links-header}}
        {{> components/common/quick-search}}
        {{> components/common/store-logo}}
    </div>
{{/if}}
```

I'm thinking I can just use the `{#if theme_settings.logo-position '==' 'left'}`   to set up the layout I am trying to get by just adding the additional logo and combining the quick-search and social-links-header components. How can I combine those components?

Answer (score 1):

Each component has a separate template file, so you could add the second logo to store-logo.html, and then copy the content from quick-search.html and paste it into social-links-header.html to combine those elements. You can also use CSS to adjust the layout--it really depends on the position you're trying to achieve.